# what is the scope of layer 2 traceroute, same subnet or outside also possible

Tags: switching

Considering,

i may have switches from different vendors in my network?

Also, how to ensure the target MAC will always exist in the MAC table of the switch

Comment: Looks like this question belongs on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

l2 traceroute is limited to a l3 domain.  It is limited to an L2 broadcast domain.  You cannot go across the subnet.

Comment: plz reply abt  how to ensure the target MAC will always exist in the MAC table of the switch

Comment: Can you please provide more details?  Normally MAC address table entries are aged out by the switch.  Some products allow for the learnt addresses to stay sticky on the switch - this works only if the product supports it AND you have access to configure such feature on the switch.